# Cannot convert value of type [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl] to required type [com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.SessionFactory]

Tags: spring, junit, liferay

I got this exception!!!

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl] to required type [com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.SessionFactory] for property 'sessionFactory': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:289)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:154)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:452)
    ... 41 more
```

Do you have any solution?

Comment: How your Spring context is defined?

Comment: Please verify your imports in the class that uses the SessionFactory

Comment: the context is defined using FileSystemXmlApplicationContext

Answer (score 0):

One of the beans that you pass `sessionFactory` to them require the Liferay one instead of the Hibernate one.

There are 2 possible mistakes:

- You made a mistake in wiring - fix that by passing Lifray's SessionFactory (create one if you don't have one already)
- The mistake is in Java class imports - fix the imports